# d3 v4 brush & zoom with two fingers touch

Tags: javascript, android, ios, d3.js, web

I have applied zoom to a selection in my d3 charts using d3 brush based on this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f48fcdb929a620ed97877e4678ab15e6 but this does not support the brush selection with "two fingers" on mobile (touch event with `e.touches.length`). How can I handle the `brush` event of the brush in d3 to handle this event to select the area inside the touches in mobile without rewriting all the `brush` handler defined in d3-brush ?